# How to display a msgbox as per the dates

Tags: vb6

**`[Part 1 - Original question]`**

I have values like 30, 31, 28 or 29 which are total days of the month.

I want to make a for loop

If I select 28 it should display a msgbox 28 times.

If I select 31 it should display a msgbox 31 times.

The code I tried:

```
Dim dayst As Variant
Dim tot1 As Variant
tot1 = DateDiff("d", "01/2011", DateAdd("m", 1, "01/2011"))
tot1 = Split(tot1, ",")
For Each dayst In tot1
   MsgBox dayst
Next
```

The above code is showing "31" in the msgbox, instead of 31 times like "1", "2", ... "31"

I want to display a msgbox 31 times incrementing from 1 to 31.

**`[Part 2 - Updated request]`**

Default Column Value Example

```
ID 1 2 ..... 31  totaldays

001 Yes Yes .... Yes 31
002 Yes Yes .... Yes 31
003 Yes Yes .... Yes 31
.....

001 is coming from table
Yes is the default column value for 1 to 31 or 1 to 28
totaldays should be no of days permonth.
```

How can I accomplish this using vb6.

Comment: tot1 returns a single number from the DateDiff. Why do you expect it to be in arrayform suitbale for splitting?

Comment: Why split whereas DateDiff return long value. Use simple for loop.

Comment: @brettdj, What is other possibilites...?

Comment: @AVD, I am getting error as type mimastch if i not used split....

Comment: @Gopal your getting a type mismatch error because your trying to do a for each against a non array, basically your making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Check brettdj's answer as I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a simple loop like this - although I dont see why you would want to have 28-31 MsgBox prompts in a row

```
Dim tot1 As Long
Dim lngDays As Long
tot1 = DateDiff("d", "01/2011", DateAdd("m", 1, "01/2011"))
For lngDays = 1 To tot1
    MsgBox lngDays
Next
```

**`Updated version - adds early exit option`**

```
Dim tot1 As Long
Dim lngDays As Long
Dim lngExit As Long
tot1 = DateDiff("d", "01/2011", DateAdd("m", 1, "01/2011"))
For lngDays = 1 To tot1
   lngExit = MsgBox(lngDays, vbOKCancel, "Press Cancel to exit")
   If lngExit = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Next
```

Comment: @BREETDJ, Thank you for your answer, How can i add a default column value in 28 or 31 columns.  For Example if 31 column header is displaying it should display default values as "Yes" in the column value.  How to do this....

Comment: @Gopal how does "column value" tie into your question? This is the first time a column header has been mentioned.

Comment: @gopal i will once I know what you mean - can you give me an example?

Comment: I'm unclear on this column piece which is probably because I'm a VBA guy and I think you are referring to a VB table. You will have to get this additional part (which should probably have been a new question) from someone else

Comment: Form their [previous question] they want to add columns to a ListView.